# PopupMenu RuntimeException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, popupmenu

Okay so I'm implement a searchable listview. Its okay and good but I want the listview item to have popupmenu. So I tried to put on some to code to implement this popupmenu on the listview and display full item details on the another activity. But I get an runtimeexception, I don't know what to do about this. Its says "unable to start componentInfo on albusmActivity java.lang.NullPointerException". Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")

    public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity {ConnectionDetector cd;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;

    // albums JSONArray
    JSONArray albums = null;                    
    EditText inputSearch;
    ImageView imgClick;
    SimpleAdapter adapter = null;               
    // albums JSON url                          
    private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album.php";

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_SONGS_COUNT = "songs_count";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
        getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check for internet connection
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(AlbumsActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Hashmap for ListView
        albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
         inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                    AlbumsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());  
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                }
            });
        // Loading Albums JSON in Background Thread
        new LoadAlbums().execute();

        // get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

        /**
         * Listview item click listener
         * TrackListActivity will be lauched by passing album id
         * */
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // on selecting a single album
                // TrackListActivity will be launched to show tracks inside the album
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);

                // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album
                String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);               

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });     

        imgClick = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.row_click_imageView1);
        imgClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(AlbumsActivity.this,imgClick);
                pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,pop.getMenu());

                pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                        Toast.makeText(AlbumsActivity.this,"text"+item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(AlbumsActivity.this,NexActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                pop.show();
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 2){
            String message = data.getStringExtra("Message");
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
            text.setText(message);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all Albums by making http request
     * */
    class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Listing Albums ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Albums JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

            try {               
                albums = new JSONArray(json);

                if (albums != null) {
                    // looping through All albums
                    for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item values in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        albumsList.add(map);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                /*  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList,
                            R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                    TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);*/

                    AlbumsActivity.this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList, R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(AlbumsActivity.this.adapter);

                }
            });

        }

    }
```

}

```
this is the line from 138-144



    @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
            Toast.makeText(AlbumsActivity.this,"text"+item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(AlbumsActivity.this,NexActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            return true;
        }
```

Here's my log details

```
09-23 21:29:54.161: D/dalvikvm(867): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
09-23 21:29:55.721: E/Trace(867): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-23 21:29:57.711: D/dalvikvm(867): GC_CONCURRENT freed 146K, 10% free 2626K/2912K, paused 10ms+16ms, total 138ms
09-23 21:29:57.882: D/AndroidRuntime(867): Shutting down VM
09-23 21:29:57.892: W/dalvikvm(867): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projectsoftware/com.projectsoftware.AlbumsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at com.projectsoftware.AlbumsActivity.onCreate(AlbumsActivity.java:138)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-23 21:29:57.992: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  ... 11 more
09-23 21:30:06.961: I/Process(867): Sending signal. PID: 867 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you share your log details please?

Comment: @santalu -that is my log details below

Answer (score 0):

when onPostExecute you'r running on UiThread already.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        AlbumsActivity.this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList, R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });
        setListAdapter(AlbumsActivity.this.adapter);

    }
```

and you'r textview definition is wrong use this

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

instead of

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: which line it is? com.projectsoftware.AlbumsActivity.onCreate(AlbumsActivity.java:138)

Comment: it is the public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) with an Override

Comment: check this menu.xml and make sure there's items defined

Comment: oh i saw that. your result returns null. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android

Answer (score 0):

@santalu - this is the line from 138-144

```
@Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                            Toast.makeText(AlbumsActivity.this,"text"+item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(AlbumsActivity.this,NexActivity.class);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                            return true;
                        }
```